# How to convert string to array of objects?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a struct:

```
struct T
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Next I have a string which contains values (a, b, c) for objects of type T with char `"|"` as a separator, for example:

```
1 2 3 | 3 1 2 | 2 2 1
```

I would like  to convert that string to array of objects T. I know how to implement such conversion using C++03 but maybe C++17 has some features which maybe helpful. How would you implement it using C++17 ?

Comment: Nothing C++17-specific, but there is C++20 out since a few years that can offer you an easy solution: `std::ranges::split(output, input, std::views::split(' '));` or iterate with `for (const auto token : std::views::split(input, ' '))`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if c++17 brings here something which would make parsing easier for this. `std::getline` and `std::stringstream` are pre-modern features. We can use `nodiscard` to tell the compiler that the return value should be used.

```
[[nodiscard]] std::vector<T> parseDataToArray(const std::string& input)
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    std::stringstream ss(input);
    std::string item;

    while (std::getline(ss, item, '|'))
    {
        T obj;
        std::stringstream itemStream(item);

        itemStream >> obj.a;
        itemStream >> obj.b;
        itemStream >> obj.c;

        result.push_back(obj);
    }

    return result;
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard

```
convertStringToArray("1 2 3 | 3 1 2 | 2 2 1"); // gives warning
auto list = convertStringToArray("1 2 3 | 3 1 2 | 2 2 1"); // is OK
```

We can consider std::string_view instead of const reference to std::string.